# Salesforce object the stores Experience Search Terms

Tags: experience-cloud, digital-experience, community-cloud

I would like to download the content of the object that stores Salesforce's Experience's global search terms.  Can you tell me what object name I should be looking at?

Answer (score 1):

I found the information I was looking for in the NetworkSearchQueryFrequency object.